# Any way to 'wordwrap' long URLs in markdown for displaying URL parameters?

Tags: http, url, markdown

Trying to show a gist of HTTP traffic to a client. When I use markdown, I can't seem to find a way to have the URLs gracefully wrap. For example:

https://gist.github.com/06560154a0f00d274131

You have to individually scroll over on each URL to see the last GET params. If they wrapped, you'd be able to very quickly notice which params are present.

Previously I've been emailing HTTP traffic to a client, however I'd love to have it on Git, where I can edit mistakes, version, etc.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `<code>` tag, example

`<code>http://thisisalongurl.com?urlparam=asdfurl&urlparam=asdf&urlparam=asdf&urlparam=asdf&urlparam=asdf&urlparam=asdf&urlparam=asdf&urlparam=asdf&urlparam=asdf&urlparam=asdf&urlparam=asdf&urlparam=asdf&finalparam=asdf</code>`

Result

`http://thisisalongurl.com?urlparam=asdfurl&urlparam=asdf&urlparam=asdf&urlparam=asdf&urlparam=asdf&urlparam=asdf&urlparam=asdf&urlparam=asdf&urlparam=asdf&urlparam=asdf&urlparam=asdf&urlparam=asdf&finalparam=asdf`

Comment: Just gave that a shot and didn't see it work... Do you have an example? https://gist.github.com/kdoran/06560154a0f00d274131